# Missing column in CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, export-to-csv

So I've a 2D-array looking like this:

```
[[1 0]
[2 0]
[3 0]
[4 0]
...
```

and I want to save it to a csvfile, I know that I must use to_csv to do so.

So I tried doing :
np.savetxt("file.csv",array,delimiter=',',fmt='%d,%d'), %d is to store data as int not as the default format
But my csv file only contains the first column and not the column of zero.

Comment: Why do you have spaces between elements in your array? When I make list in list, I use comma... In any case, your script is working for me: `A = [[x,0 ] for x in range(10)];np.savetxt("file.csv",A,delimiter=',',fmt='%d,%d')`

Comment: I append two columns to make my 2D-array, that's probably why I've spaces

Comment: what is `array.shape`?

Comment: `to_csv` is a pandas method.  Why do you mention that, but use the numpy function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `array` is what you claim?  If I make it fresh:

```
In [234]: arr = np.array([[1, 0],
     ...: [2, 0],
     ...: [3, 0],
     ...: [4, 0]])

In [235]: arr
Out[235]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0]])
```

Your `savetxt` works fine (the delimiter parameter isn't needed since you included it in the fmt):

```
In [237]: np.savetxt("file.csv",arr,delimiter=',',fmt='%d,%d')

In [238]: !more file.csv
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
```

Comment: Thanks, the array that I was trying to save was a reference to another one that had other treatment and not a copy so the line of zeros was just missing

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `to_csv`.  You'd probably benefit from coding your own.  Writing from a numpy array (or any other simple data structure) to a csv file is only a few lines of code.

General structure...

Use a context manager to open the file in write mode...

```
with open('my_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
```

make a loop in there to loop over the rows in your array.

write the row with commas between the elements by converting the elements to strings and writing them with another loop (or with a `join` command)

write a newline character to start the next row.

Give it a try.  Comment back if you are stuck.